# Line integral polar coordinates

Tags: integration, substitution

What I am uncertain of is how this was derived? I know that $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$ but i dont get how we get the dy/dx inside the arctan.
$$\oint\limits_{c}\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\oint\limits_{c} \mathrm{d}\arctan(\mathrm{dy}/\mathrm{dx}) $$

Comment: Why do you think that there is dy/dx inside the arctan?

Comment: Yes this is wrong. It should be $\oint_c \text{d}\arctan\frac yx.$

Comment: Ok thank you. Nice to get that clarified.

Comment: Keep in mind that I assumed that $\theta$ is the polar angle (so that the computed integral is the winding number of the curve).